# Customer Portal.......Pagination Page is not Translated

Tags: apex, customer-portal

Here I have problem in Customer portal.when i am logging as any other language like japanese,italian,german,etc..in that 3 or 4 pages uses the pagination code..in that word"page" is not translated as logging language....

here is the snapshot of the problem.....

[image]

and now here is the code for the pagination from the controller

[image]

So here What can i do to translate rounded marked "page" word as per the selected language in customer portal....

SO please give me suggestion to solve this type of problem...

Answer (score 1):

If you have created your own table on custom page then, You can solve this problem by creating  Labels in your org (YourName -> setup -> create-->Custom Labels). These Custom labels can be transled in other language and Can be used on Visual force Page by user {!$Label.YOUR_Lable_Name}. Using Label is a best practice.

Below link helps you 
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cl_translate_edit.htm&language=en_US

Comment: thanx for replay but i have already made label of "page" and translate in other languages unfortunatally it was not resolved....i think in <td> tag id='ClosedPagerDiv' is responsible for pagination......but it's a standard salesforce id so how can i find it?

Comment: Can you post you code here may be it will help to understand.

Comment: Ok thanks for your prompt response...i am done using jquery...

Comment: Can you post the markup where you are calling the label and passing the language parameter to the page?